# Custom Payment Method Not Showing in Frontend

Tags: payment, frontend

I've created a new payment method in Magento1.7. But it's not showing up in frontend. In the backend, options are showing. Below is the code,

config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_TelephoneOrder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_TelephoneOrder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <telephoneorder>
                <class>Company_TelephoneOrder_Helper</class>
            </telephoneorder>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <telephoneorder>
                <class>Company_TelephoneOrder_Model</class>
            </telephoneorder>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <telephone_payment>
            <telephone_order>
                <active>1</active>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <title>Telephone Order</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <model>telephoneorder/telephone</model>
            </telephone_order>
        </telephone_payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Telephone.php

```
class Company_TelephoneOrder_Model_Telephone extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'telephoneorder';
    protected $_isInitializeNeeded = true;

   protected $_canUseInternal = true;

 protected $_canUseForMultishipping = true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following node to your `etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    ...
    <default>
    ...
        <payment>
            <telephoneorder>
                <model>telephoneorder/telephone</model>
            </telephoneorder>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```